# unsuccessful upgrade from 11.10 to 12.4 LTS

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, laptop, samsung

I had upgrade from ubuntu 11.10, that runs alongside windows7, to 12.4 lts in a netbook Samsung nc110. After upgrade Ubuntu doesnt run. After log in all the screen is in  blue.
What can i do? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Before going any further, where are your personal files stored?? You should perhaps think about backing them up or rescuing them before proceeding?
2. Have you tried booting Ubuntu from a Live USB?
3. Can you still boot into Windows??

Comment: Afortunately my personal files are stored at windows, and i still boot into windows. Should i unistall ubuntu from windows, and try to download it again?

Comment: First ensure backup of files.  Then test using LiveCD.  Can you identify the video chip and other details for this hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I find this answer in another similar question, and it works for me:
"CTRL+Alt+F1",
Log in, After That:
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade"
And it started downloading some files, when it finished:
"sudo shutdown -r now"
And when I restarted Ubuntu 12.4Lts was running OK.